# Use text to speech on a voice call

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Is it possible to use the text-to-speech engine to send a message through a voice call? Like an answering machine.

It's also possible to monitor an outgoing voice call to read out loud a text when the other point answers the phone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During a call, speech generated by TextToSpeech engine won't be audible to the other end of the call.

Answer (score 3):

No.  In typical android phone designs, the in-call audio bypasses the processor on which linux/android are running, so you can't directly inject anything into it.