# Injecting text to speech into calls? [Android]

Tags: android

Is it possible to inject Text To Speech into voice calls on Android? As in, redirect the Text To Speech's output into the Microphone, so the person on the other end hears it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use text to speech on a voice call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203801/use-text-to-speech-on-a-voice-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is impossible due to Android's privacy limitations.

Comment: Well, I guess you can just make sure the speaker is open and play the sound out. So the microphone of the phone probably will record the sound and the person on the another end could get it.

Comment: Maybe check out this thread on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795161/how-do-i-enable-the-android-speaker-during-a-call-from-code , I don't know if it worked or not.

Comment: And this one too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725367/how-to-turn-on-speaker-for-incoming-call-programmatically-in-android-l , they both gave out the solution to turn on the microphone during the call.